# Access twitter user object using lookup_user

Tags: python, twitter

The following code,

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
user_lookup = twitter.show_user(screen_name = username)
```

returns a single user's twitter object as a dictionary, allowing access to each attribute, like `user_lookup['followers_count']`. I'd like to do this in bulk. I know that twitter's `lookup_user` allows bulk requests up to 100 screen_names using code like,

```
user_lookup = twitter.lookup_user(screen_name = usergroup)
```

where `usergroup` is a string of names separated by commas. But `lookup_user`, unlike `show_user`, returns a list. I haven't seen an easy way to access the individual attributes from the list like I can from the dictionary. How can I access each attribute for each user in the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the list elements are of type dictionary. So the following works when using `lookup_user` as shown in the question,

```
user_lookup[index]['followers_count']
```

where index is the list item number.